# Creating lagged variable only generates missings

Tags: stata

I'd like to `generate` a lagged variable of the variable `gdp_cp` in my dataset. The dataset looks like this:

```
year    | gdp_cp
1975    | 5.414e+14
1976    | 5.786e+14
1977    | 6.293e+14
1978    | 6.787e+14
1979    | 7.211e+14
1980    | 7.923e+14
1981    | 8.552e+14
1982    | 8.744e+14
1983    | 9.511e+14
1984    | 1.017e+15
```

so I tried to tell Stata that this dataset is a time series using the command:

```
tsset gdp_cp year, yearly
```

In the output window, I got the following:

```
panel variable:  gdp_cp (weakly balanced)
 time variable:  year, 1975 to 2010
         delta:  1 year
```

Then I wanted to create a lagged version of `gdp_cp` by using the command:

```
gen gdp_lagged = L1.gdp_cp
```

Unfortunately Stata creates only missing values... so what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first variable in the `tsset` command should be `id` (whatever it is in your dataset, e.g., *country, region, household*, etc.). If you add `gdp` in that command, Stata uses `gdp` for identification of each observation, i.e. treats each entry as independent from the rest, thus, there couldn't be any lags.

Comment: In addition, it's not a good idea to hold values of the order of 10^14 or 10^15 in a `float` variable, or arguably in any variable. Even if your data are given to numerous significant figures, and you believe them all, a `float` does not have enough bits to guarantee holding them all exactly. Further, if you compute with `float`s rather than `double`s, you lose precision and it's all too likely that coefficient estimates, etc., will end up being very large or very small and, either way, awkward to handle. Choose a sensible unit, e.g. billions in the currency used.